# PHP: insert 3 input text in 1 textarea pressing one button

Tags: javascript, php, textarea

I Have 3 input text in a form, that i would like to joini like this after pressing a button:

TextA-TextB TextC.

I also would like that will be  positioniting on th first free line of the text area.

if for eaxmple ther is this situation:

2018-12345 25.00,

i would like that inserting the datas in the 3 text, will become like this:

2018-12345 25.00

TextA-TextB TextC

I imagine that i need javascript and calling the function with event onclick on the button, but i am not into javascript, because of that i am asking for your kind help.

Comment: can you add the code you tried to use?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast answer.

I tried to combine a couple of codes that i found online, but i always get error 404 when I try it on fiddle:

```
<script>

function fillMessage() {
    var annoTA1 = document.getElementById('annoTA') + " ";
    var numTess1 = document.getElementById('numTess') + " ";
    var impVer1 = document.getElementById('impVer1') + " ";

msg.value = annoTA1.value + numTess1.value + impVer1.value;

 var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
document.getElementById("message").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;


 var Message= "";
    function addText(text) {
        Message+= text
    }
document.getElementById("message").value = Message;


} </script>
```

and for the onclick event I used:

```
<button onclick="fillMessage()">Aggiungi Nuova Tessera</button>
```

the original fiddle is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qmrt7z0w/

and plus I added

```
var Message= "";
        function addText(text) {
            Message+= text to test there before.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this script:

```
<script>
$('#btn').on('click', function (){
   var insertText = $('#annoTA').val() + " ";
   insertText += $('#numTess').val() + " ";
   insertText += $('#impVer').val() + " ";
   if(document.getElementById("annoTAG").value == ' ')
{
    $('#annoTAG').val( $('#annoTAG').val() + insertText);
   }
   else
   {
    $('#annoTAG').val( $('#annoTAG').val() + '\n' + insertText);
   }
});
</script>
```

And for the button i had to use:

```
<input type="button" value="Aggiungi Nuova Tessera" id="btn" />
```

Otherwise is not working...

Everything works good now, just that when I am inserting. The first row, it starts with a space. I tried to adding the backspace like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("annoTAG").value == ' ')
    {
        $('#annoTAG').val( $('#annoTAG').val() + '\b '+ insertText);
       }
```

But did not works. Any suggestions?

Thanks